# Unity - Button still interactable even when interactable is set to false

Tags: unity, gui

my button can still be pressed in-game even if I set it to `button.interactable = false;`

What I'm trying to achieve is when the Panel `CropsPanel` is opened, or active in Unity, I want the `EquipmentButton` to be disabled and to be not usable by the user. Here is the code I've written:

```
 public void Start () 
     {
         GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;  
         if (CropsPanel.activeInHierarchy == true)
         {
           EquipmentButton.interactable = false;
         }
     }
```

I have also set all buttons in the inspector, placed a `Debug.Log("msg here");` to see if the particular code is working. But I can't seem to get it working. Am I missing something? Thanks guys!

Comment: Workaround for that, i always make sure that the target image has "Raycast Target" set to false.

Comment: I dont think activeinhierarchy works with start. I think there needs to be an listener. Try to quickly add an input in thenupdate function and try to trigger the above function in a new void. Other than that, i also believe that activehierarchy needs a apecific parent. If its still not working, post your declaration and the rest of your script that might be important.

Answer (score 1):

```
//using public you can directly drag a button from Hierarchy and drop it in inspector
public Button EquipmentButton;
void Start()
{
//You can link the button on runtime using this line.
  EquipmentButton = GameObject.Find("Button_Name_In_Hierarchy").GetComponent<Button>();
//Now disable it
  EquipmentButton.intractable = false;
}
```

initially CropsPanel is disable means don't declare it in start function. keep it in an update or create some other function to check it

```
void Update()
{
  if (CropsPanel.activeInHierarchy == true)
     {
       EquipmentButton.interactable = false;
     }
}
```